# How can I overwrite Windows 7 with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, hard-drive, disk, disk-usage

Windows 7 runs unreasonably slow, so I decided to install Ubuntu instead.

I clicked Install but it says that I do not have at least 4. 4GB of disk space. But my hard disk's capacity is is 320 GB.

How can I fix this and get Ubuntu installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 6):

Please be aware that you will be **permanently removing your windows installation**. This process **cannot be undone**. You will loose every data on every partition you delete. Keeping a **backup is your responsibility**.

Said that, first you have to decide how you want to install Ubuntu.
I can suggest three workarounds.

- By default installation menu: This has an option to **use entire disk**. the installer will automatically optimize the partitioning process.
- The fail-safe option: To install Ubuntu, use your entire hard disk and delete every partition on it. To do this Boot from Live CD and choose the option to `try Ubuntu`.

  Once you are on the live desktop session, find [GParted partition editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net); or **ubuntu disk partitioner**. With these wonderful tools you can delete and repartition your hard-disk very efficiently. I suggest you to delete every partition and then install Ubuntu.

  PS: I am not aware out of above said tools, which one is present in the Ubuntu 12.04 (latest) live CD. Both of them were present in the Ubuntu 10.10  (now unsupported) version.
- Geek Method: This method is my favorite, gives most flexibility; however bit tricky.
  This is a text based (CLI) installation method.

  Download and install [Ubuntu 12.04 minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) straightaway. This installation process is straight forward and most powerful. As a newbie (when option comes) choose the option to use the whole disk drive. Once the system in installed and it reboots, you get a command line interface from where you have endless options to build your system according to your needs.

  You can install software with `sudo apt-get install ...` (see examples below). But first run this command, which makes sure you're installing the current versions:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  If you want to install `ubuntu-desktop`, which provides the GNOME Unity GUI and related applications, the command is:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  ```

  If you want to get a Kubuntu (KDE) environment then use this command instead:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
  ```

Hope this might help.. Good luck...

Comment: {quote}PS: I am not aware out of above said tools, which one is present in the Ubuntu 12.04 (latest) live CD{quote}     GParted is the default now the other one is no longer on the disk as far as I know.

Comment: @TrailRider i want to reconfirm, is gParted present in Ubuntu 12.04 live CD?

Comment: I apologise, I could have worded that better.  Yes Gparted is on the live CD