# Accessing existing Windows C drive from Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu through Windows XO, which I need to stop using. On start-up if I choose Ubuntu I can't find my existing files which are stored on the hard drive, and it looks as if the file system is empty (says 77gb free). How do I get the information and get rid of windows please? And if I save any files in Ubuntu will it start to overwrite my windows data? Many thanks Just seen there is a C: and D: drive in windows. Will windows installer have put Ubuntu on to the D: drive? and if so how to find C: from Ubuntu. Thanks, I am proper novice

**Edit** Output from `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0xaa0213ba 

    Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System 

/dev/sda1 63 12594959 6297448+ 12 Compaq diagnostics 
/dev/sda2 * 12594960 161585151 74495096 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda3 161585152 312578047 75496448 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Can you still choose XP and see your files?  If yes you should be able to get to your data.  Open a terminal and enter `sudo fdisk -l` and edit your post with the response so we can advise further.

Comment: thanks- yes xp still opens and files are still there. Sorry don't know what opening terminal is! Is it like command prompt? and how do i find it? many thanks

Comment: press CTRL+ALT+T together and a terminal window will open type the command `sudo fdisk -l` and when prompted enter your password. Edit your question by copying and pasting the output.  This will tell us more about your system and we can advise further.

Comment: thanks for help so far!  Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xaa0213ba

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63    12594959     6297448+  12  Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda2   *    12594960   161585151    74495096    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       161585152   312578047    75496448    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Ubuntu as a [Wubi installation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29). To access your windows drives and files, you should be able to see a "Host" drive when you open the file browser, to the left hand side, under the label "Computer".

It would be better if you could install ubuntu as a standard installation rather than as wubi. To see how to install ubuntu as a standard installation by replacing windows, see this:

- [How to install ubuntu replacing windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)

Be warned that this will remove your windows files, so backup all your files and folders.

See the difference between wubi and a standard installation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation).

Comment: thanks for your response. there does't seem to be a drive labelled host.just lots of folders named with long strings of numbers. I think I will save my data onto a usb (just ordered 256Gb), and then erase windows. presumably I need to make a bootable usb first and then boot by turning on laptop and pressing f12?

Comment: If you are gonna dual boot, you should proceed by first backing up all your data.

Comment: @user260849 yes, you can change boot order by F12 or F2. You can make a bootable USB just on the same USB stick you store your files.