# How to remove default installed Windows 8.1 and replace with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, windows, uninstall

I've just bought a new computer with default installed Windows 8.1 and i absolutely hate it.

I've been using Ubuntu before, but it was totally different for me, because i installed it on an empty hard drive.

So, my question is, what do I have to do (step by step) to completely get rid of Windows and install the newest version of Ubuntu?

Thank you very much!

Comment: See also [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/331353/22949) and [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/22949)

Answer (score 2):

See step number 4 here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

When allocating drive space, you will have the option of utilizing the whole drive which would remove windows.