# Install Ubuntu Single Boot (Without Windows)

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a scientist who must use Linux, because this OS is free (open source), and I want change from Windows to Ubuntu.

The problem is, how make my PC (Laptop) just have one OS (Linux) without Windows beside it (Ubuntu)? I wish I could uninstall Windows from my PC and change to Linux Ubuntu. And I want my PC just have one OS, that is Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Easy: stick the installation DVD into system, boot, and during partitioning delete all partitions and recreate them for Ubuntu. If you have anything of interest on your system: make a backup.

Comment: and here is the general installation page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to have an Ubuntu. First of all delete whatever you have on your PC. Then change format of your hard disk and use [EXT 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) format instead of NTFS. After that divide your hard disk into some parts, Like a special space for root ( / ), swap (virtual memory) and home.

My recommendation is to use 50 GB for root, twice your RAM space for swap and rest of it for your home.

Install Ubuntu and Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Most of us use a USB jump drive/SDcard to install Ubuntu and not a DVD anymore.  You need a newer BIOS to boot from USB which you can check out on your computer in advance. You need at least 2G on the jump drive/SD card.  You use a boot disk utility to burn the iso on the USB drive.  Many of us use Unetbootin which has both a Windows and a Linux version.

You can go to the Ubuntu site where you download the iso for the latest version.  In this area they they have nice tutorials on how to burn a USB boot drive as well as how to install Ubuntu.  It is very easy to reformat the drive and install Ubuntu over the old Windows installation, just follow your nose when you do the installation.  Have fun.