# Ubuntu 14.04.3 installation

Tags: xubuntu

I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04.3 LOS with a USB. When I run the install it prompts me through the install but it's not installing over windows. I'd like it to format the drive windows is on and install the boot loader to that drive. (SATA1). When I install ubuntu and re insert my USB it loads up the selections to install or try without installing. I ran through the install like 3 times. When I remove the USB nothing not even Windows will boot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)

Comment: You should close this as you have asked the question again providing more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make ubuntu use SATA-1 Drives?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/677643/how-do-i-make-ubuntu-use-sata-1-drives)

Answer (score 0):

espero ayudarte, verás ,para instalar Ubuntu asi como cualquier distro linux juntu con Windows,  depes particionar el disco duro,  por lo que tendrás que investigar que son particiones, hasta ahi muy bien, luego debes saber configurar la BIOS es posible que usted tenga UEFI que creo que es una BIOS que funciona con una interfaz gráfica o algo así,  pero lo que realmente importa es que tengas en cuenta el orden de arranque de los sistemas operativos,  primero debes poner ubuntu, luego Windows,  si todo sale bien, entonces cuándo enciendas tu máquina veras una interfaz textual , por lo general morada, ese programa de entrada se llama GRUB y permite decidir cual sistema operativo SO correr,

●intenta cuidadosamente configurar la BIOS las formas que sea posible,  pero hazlo con información a la mano.
●no tiene sentido que reinstales Ubuntu. 
ESPERO HABERTE AYUDADO :)