# Melting Windows' partitions together while installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I have Win7 on my laptop with two partitions (C and D). I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I don't need those separate partitions - I just need a whole HDD for my Ubuntu (and I know it's nice to have separate partitions for `/home` etc., but I don't really need that right now and I'm not an advanced Linux user yet). Can I just choose 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' to "melt" my partitions together? Or I have to mess with 'Something else' option (I'd really love to avoid it for now)?

**UPD**: Suggested duplicate is wrong, because my question is specific about managing partiotions. The answer below solved my problem. Right now I'm writing from my fresh Ubuntu. Indeed, you can simply choose 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu'.

Comment: Start your live-ubuntu and use **try** Ubuntu. You will find programs like *gnome-disks* or **gparted** and delete all partitions. **Alternatively:** During installation you can choose in the partition section **others** to make your partitioning as you want .

Comment: If there is no gparted installed by default, can I install it to my live 'try Ubuntu' session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" to repartition the drive to Ubuntu-only.

It's a good choice if your want Ubuntu to be the only OS on the entire hard disk, and wish to remove all traces of the older OS.

**Warning**:  'Erase disk' means *exactly* what it says. If you have any data you wish to preserve, save it someplace else (off that disk) before starting. Not a different partition on the same disk - those will be erased. If you have a Windows Product Key you wish to save for future re-use, *write it down* before erasing the disk.

Comment: Yeah, I wish to entirely remove Windows and forget this nightmare. I need only Ubuntu, and all my files are now moved to another storage.